How to use Resources in ktor (client side)?
The documentation itself is confusing (to me). I can't understand how it helps, what problem it solves, and how it works.
For example:
@Resource("/articles")
class Articles() {
    @Resource("{id}")
    class Id(val parent: Articles = Articles(), val id: Long)
}

Is this Articles class the same as the DTO class? Why is that parent parameter of the child class necessary?

A resource functionality is a structured way of representing the path of a server endpoint. Since the Resource annotation is shared and available for the client and the server, the resource classes can be reused to keep information about the endpoints in one place.
The parent property of the child class is required to bind several resources into one. The class nesting is optional and only done for visual grouping.
